# FaceRecognizer OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am currently working with face recognition for gender detection. I just tried OpenCV lib to support my research. From what I read on some paper, to do classification or recognition are:

PCA (Training) -> SVM (Identify or predict) -> result

From OpenCV gender recognition  tutorial, It is using Fisher that adapt LDA algorithm. I learned from the codes example that Fisherfaces is used to training and predict. PCA and LDA are on the same level with different approach.

I would like to know if Fisherfaces (model->predict) is included SVM as prediction method or else ? How prediction on OpenCV work?

Comment: opencv's facerecognizer classes use a plain 1-nearest-neighbour search (L2/CHISQR-norm) for classification. but sure, feel free to try an SVM instead !

Comment: can I combine opencv LDA with opencv SVM ? so dataset trained with LDA but predict using SVM ?

Comment: the PCA and LDA stages are more a 'feature reduction' or 'filtering' pass. so, sure, why not ? just be bold, and rip the existing code apart ;)

Comment: thanks, I'll try. currently I'm using directly the example code of gender recognition on opencv using fisher(LDA) as training and prediction. Later, I'll try to combine both.

Comment: one step after the other, ofc. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right,PCA is an unsupervised method,but LDA is a supervised method.So you can use LDA to do the classify job.

Comment: how LDA on OpenCV predict the result ? using SVM or k-nearest or else ?

Comment: Commonly after the LDA process k-nearest is the most simple way to predict your result... you can refere this link: https://github.com/bytefish/opencv/tree/master/lda/src